# Integrating R and Flex

Tags: apache-flex, r

How can you integrate R and Flex (e.g. web server using rapache)?

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed on the R help mailing list

[Dynamic visualisation of R data using Adobe FLEX](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e6/help/09/05/13430.html)

One suggestion was to use [RServe](http://rosuda.org/Rserve/example.shtml).

The presentation [Building Web Dashboards with R](http://files.meetup.com/1225993/Dataspora_Building_Web_Dashboards_with_R.pdf) was mentioned as a related read, but doesn't contain any Flex-specific information.

[Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) and [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/) were mentioned as alternatives to Flex.